# Storing variables in array in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables

I have a code in which I create a large number of the same variable and I would like to store all of its values. Normally I would use `for loops` for this and store all of them, but due to some complications it is not possible at the moment.

I have to calculate the variable `x`, store it as `x1`. Calcute the `x` with different conditions and store it as `x2` etc. The problem I have that I would have to manually change all the `x`'s in my code to `x2`, `x3`, `x4` etc. And there are a lot of them. Is there a way to it more efficiently?

To better illustrate:

```
x1 = 5*y(1);

%some calculations with y

x2 = 5*y(2);

% some claculations with y

x3=5*y(3);
```

Comment: Could you illustrate with something closer to what you are actually using? Because I am guessing it won't be as straight-forward as just scaling by `5` or is it? My pointer for you is still hovering around at suggesting vectorized methods.

Comment: so why can't you store it as `x(1) = 5*y(1)`  so on and so forth?

Comment: Yes I could, but I would have modify all the x's in my code to x(1) and x(2) etc. It would take a lot of time

Comment: Just use "search and replace" function in any text editor. It should not be that hard. `x(1)` and `x(2)` are the right way to go.

Comment: @Andrey my answer below indicates how to do that programmatically inside of MATLAB using regular expressions. Then again, most text editors will have similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really desperate you could use `eval` and loop through all of your variable names, assuming they are numbered 1 through `n`.

```
count = 1;
while exist(['x',num2str(count)],'var')
    eval(['x(count)=x',num2str(count),';'])
    count = count + 1;
end
```

This code assumes everything is numbered `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc. It will continue looping until the next "sequential" `x` no longer exists. This would go at the end of whatever script or function you are running after all the declarations have happened.

Just note that storing everything the way you did initially is very frowned upon. It makes code hard to read and cumbersome, and it not very dynamic.

Either way, the code above should do the trick.

You could also write a regular expression to replace all `xn` and whatever instances to `x(n)`.

Just run the following lines of code, giving it the file name you want to convert, and boom it will handle all of the replacement for you

```
fileName = 'findReplace.m';
replaced = regexprep(fileread(fileName),'x([0-9]+)','x($1)');
fh = fopen(fileName,'w');
    fprintf(fh,replaced);
fclose(fh);
```

Comment: For completeness, maybe you should add a vectorised version of the calculations as well?

Comment: @kkuilla I do not know if there is a simple way to vectorize this.

Comment: I misread the question. Apologies. The question was how to change the variable names. My brain automatically thought that the question was about how to store `x1`,x2` more efficiently e.g  `x(1)`, `x(2)`. +1 though...

Comment: @kkuilla Thank you. I really think the easiest solution would be to replace all instances of `x1` with `x(1)` etc. The second portion does this. I mean both solutions are valid, just the first one, having to use `eval`, will run kinda slowly and is frowned upon, especially with large numbers of variables